# Who would be awarded the nomination in the event something happened to the candidate with the most delegates?

Tags: united-states, parties, nomination

Let's use the current situation: Sanders and Biden are the top 2 leaders for the DNC and it looks like Biden might win.  Would Sanders be automatically given the nomination if Biden was declared unable to continue to run for health reasons?

Comment: Not sure how this works in nominating conventions, but in the US, being dead is not a bar to being elected: https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/26281/4-dead-politicians-who-still-got-elected

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate, the other question is in regards to two people who have already been nominated and are running for President.  My question is asking about 2 people from the same party running for the nomination of the party and the answer to the questions are very different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sanders would not be given the nomination. If no one wins a majority of the delegates going into the convention then it becomes a brokered convention. More specifically if, in the first round of voting, one candidate does not reach 50%+1 of the delegates then there is another round of voting.

In the first round delegates are pledged to the candidate hence MUST vote for him. In the second, and subsequent rounds, the delegates may vote for anyone of their choosing. In addition super delegates are able to vote as well.

Look up the 1924 Democratic National Convention to see an interesting example of how this has played out in the past.

Comment: What happens if a delegate votes for a candidate other than the one they're pledged to?

Comment: Is that true, even if the candidate is dead? Would Biden's delegates really be required to vote for him if he was dead, instead of being released to vote for whoever they think is best?

Comment: @Sean - My understanding is that they don't have a choice. My guess is that the first round vote is pro forma and for optics as opposed to vote counting. I'll look that up as it is interesting.

Comment: @divibisan - That's a good question. I just did a keyword search on the Democratic Party's Delegate Selection Rules and didn't find anything.